# Host WCF app on godaddy results in errors

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have created a WCF app but while hosting it on godaddy (shared hosting) I am facing issue. In my local I was able to access .svc file from IIS but after uploading on godaddy it started throwing errors.

I am totally new in hosting type of work on shared server. So no idea weather i have coded something wrongly, configured wrongly or uploaded on server wrongly? I am using MS Sql server and .net framework 3.5.

i am getting below error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

The type 'WCF35app.LinkuService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'WCF35app.LinkuService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
```

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The type 'WCF35app.LinkuService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.]
System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +62739
System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1429
System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/WCF35app/LinkuSystem.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation. The exception message is: The type 'WCF35app.LinkuService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..]
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +486572
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +174
System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +345998
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9683593
```

Web.config code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" />
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
        <service name="WCF35app.LinkuService" behaviorConfiguration="WCF35app.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://augustinfotechhosting.com/WCF35app/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCF35app.ILinkuService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <!--
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCF35app.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information,
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes,
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

my .svc file has a lines of code as below.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
Service="WCF35app.LinkuService" 
CodeBehind="~/LinkuService.cs"
%>
```

Comment: Put IP address in <dns value="localhost"/>. Also enpoint address is blank.

Comment: ip means server ip right ? By applying server ip and put your suggested code, but still issue is there.

Comment: How you have compiled service? In X86 mode? Does your godaddy server runs on 64 bit? Check this.

Comment: Our godaddy server runs on x86 mode.

Comment: OK next is how you have build? In  realease mode or debug mode? What is output path for build? From where you have copied Dll and where you have pasted in web server location? As your code shows  <compilation debug="true" />